accept this answer (この質問を採用) を押した後もコメント欄は使用できる？
現在stack overflow上で質問しており、ある方が回答していただいたため問題は解決したのですが、その人にもう少し質問したいと思いコメントを残したのですが、この途中でaccept this answer(この質問を採用)のチェックボタンを押した場合その方はまだ質問に答えることはできますか？
問題は解決したので相手への意思表示として押したいのですが、相手がコメント欄にこれ以上入力ができなくなったらと考えると押せません。チェックボタンを押した後の挙動を教えていただけると幸いです。

前置き:
質問されているのは恐らく TeX - Stack Exchange のようですが、基本的に各サイトでの困りごと・質問等は各サイトごとのメタにて投稿してもらう形になります。
今回の質問に限っては、関連サイトを含め共通の仕様に関する質問なのでこちらで回答しておきます。

「回答の承認」と「コメント」機能はそれぞれ独立しているので、承認後も引き続き自由にコメントを付けることは可能です。
「回答の承認」は、解決したとき、回答に対して感謝の気持ちでプラスで信用度を相手に送るための機能…位に捉えてください。
コメントについてもう少しだけ詳しく説明すると…

自分自身が質問したページにおいては、質問・回答に対していつでもコメントを付ける事が可能です。
他のユーザーが投稿した質問ページにおいてコメントを付けるには、一定以上の信用度が必要になります。 - 関連ヘルプ: コメントとは？

参考ヘルプ:
回答が「承認された」とはどういう意味ですか？

回答の承認は、質問に対して完全な回答が得られたという決定的で最終的な表明ではありません。単に、作成者が個人的に満足する回答を得たということを意味するだけであって、すべてのユーザーが回答を承認するわけではなく、後で新しくより良い回答が投稿されたときに、承認したユーザーが承認された回答を変更するとは限りません。


わかりやすい回答と参考サイトを紹介してくださりありがとうございます！おかげで理解が深まりました。この度はありがとうございました！
